# ¿Cómo puedo crear dominios con restricciones de longitud y su valor contenido?

Tags: postgresql

Tengo problemas para comprender la estructuración de un código con el propósito de añadir restricciones como de tamaño, y de valores contenidos dentro de campos mediante dominios.

Como por ejemplo, si quisiera hacer un dominio que solo contenga 9 dígitos, con valores del 0 al 9.

Entiendo la estructura de la creación del dominio, más no la restricción en sí, o qué palabras se utilizarían para implementarlas.

```
create domain "cptype" as varchar(9)
check (value ~ '^\d{9}$');
```

Ese es el código que intenté implementar

Comment: Si pides el código no te lo darán, aquí solucionamos los problemas que las personas han tenido al implementar su solución, si no haz intentado nada, te invito a que lo hagas

Comment: Y por cierto, lee [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Tu código es correcto. Lo puedes usar para campos de tipo `cptype`. Para probarlo se puede "castear" el tipo `text` a `ctype` como se ve en el siguiente ejemplo:

```sql
create domain "cptype" as varchar(9) check (value ~ '^\d{9}$');
select '012345678'::cptype; -- ok!
select 'A12345678'::cptype; -- error tiene letra!
select '12345678'::cptype; -- error es más corto!
```

Si quisieras de 1 a 9 dígitos podrías usar una de las dos opciones de acá abajo. Hay que fijarse que la primera está basada en texto (o sea es un texto no se pueden sumar los números salvo que se los "castee" a números). Y la segunda son números sin decimales, que se pueden usar para sumar, promediar, etc sin necesidad de volver a transformarlos.

```sql
create domain "c9type" as varchar(9) check (value ~ '^\d{1,9}$');
select '12345678'::c9type; -- ok!
select '12345678'::c9type + '1'::c9type; -- no se pueden sumar, no son números!

create domain "d9number" as numeric(9,0);
select '12334'::d9number; -- ok!
select '12334'::d9number + '1'::d9number; -- ok se pueden sumar, son números!
```